# Taking Values of a Form and Using Them for Comparison in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, variables

I'm attempting to create an HTML-based game. The game is supposed to use a  or  tag to accept data from the user. I'd like to then assign the data entered to a variable in Javascript for comparison. The comparison would then be used to alter the page, bringing the next part of the game into view. How would I assign the value of the input that the user types into to a Javascript variable for comparison?

I thought something along the lines of:

```
function(){
    document.getElementByID("submit");

}
```

would work for this situation, but I'm not sure.

The code I already have is rather simple, as you can see here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zulfe/L88vq/)

I'm pretty new to JS/jQuery, so forgive me if this question is just incredibly easy to answer!

Comment: All that bit of javascript is doing is getting the element (your submit button) as a javascript object.

Comment: if the user types into an <input id=usr>, the text is essentially already a JS variable, document.getElementById("usr").value, or in newer browsers, simply usr.value.

Comment: Honestly I recommend you google something like 'javascript tutorial' and 'jquery tutorial' - you need to understand the basics before you can ask questions...

Comment: I see, thanks for all of the help. I've found some help on W3Schools, and added it to my JSFiddle but it's still not working... Any help? http://jsfiddle.net/Zulfe/L88vq/1/

Comment: Ah, the problem is that you can't use forms in JSFiddle, it causes the page to misunderstand the intent of the submit button and makes the display box reload the page. 
I guess this is something I'll have to take to a local area for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.

It seems like the way you are going is using a button to say "read my input now".

In that case, you can add an event handler to the button to read what is in there.

See the following:

```
<h3>You've entered a dungeon. Do you want to CONTINUE or EXIT?</h3>
<div id="actionInterface">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" value="User"/>
    <button id="clickMe">Enter Option</button>
</div>
<script>
    var myVar;
    $("#clickMe").click(function(){
        myVar = $("#myInput").val();    
        alert(myVar);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I entered this code here: http://jsfiddle.net/Zulfe/L88vq/2/
I still can't seem to get it to work, any ideas?

Comment: It has to do with how the fiddle using your js. I don't understand the fiddle enough to fix it, but look at this one where it is not relying on the js section of the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/L88vq/3/

Comment: I see, that's weird. I'll move the entire project to a local network address that will both support the JS and give me a better view for how others will see it.

Thanks again for the help, I'll upvote and submit this as a working answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will put the value of an object into a variable:

```
function(){
var x = document.getElementById("my_object").value;
}
```